# How can I wrap a polymorphic React component in another polymorphic component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a generic `Text` component that uses a `tag` prop to support dynamically setting the underlying HTML tag. I'd like to write a wrapper component that pre-sets the `group` prop on the `Text` component while retaining the ability to pass any native HTML element. This is the code that I have:

```
interface BaseTextProps<T extends ElementType> {
  tag?: T;
  size: '100' | '200' | '300' | '400' | '500' | '600' | '700' | '800';
  children: ReactNode;
}

type TextProps<T extends ElementType> = BaseTextProps<T> & {
  group: 'display' | 'code';
}

function Text<T extends ElementType = 'span'>({
  tag,
  group,
  size,
  children,
  ...rest
}: TextProps<T> & Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof TextProps<T>>) {
  const Component = tag ?? 'span';
  return <Component {...rest}>{children}</Component>;
}

type DisplayProps<T extends ElementType> = BaseTextProps<T> & {
  size: '100' | '200' | '300';
}

export function Display<T extends ElementType>({
  tag,
  size,
  children,
}: DisplayProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Text group="display" size={size} tag={tag}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
}
```

TypeScript is able to correctly type the `Text` component when passed a string for the `tag` prop. For example, the following works correctly:

```
function Name() {
    return (
        <Text tag="p" size="100" group="display">Hello</Text>
    )
}
```

However, I am unable to correctly type the `Display` wrapper. TypeScript gives the following error:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; group: "display"; tag: T | undefined; size: 
"100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500"; }' is not assignable to type 
'Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof TextProps<T>>'. ts(2322)
```

This makes sense given that the type `Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof TextProps<T>>` shouldn't have any types, but I don't understand why TypeScript is using a partial type instead of the full prop type `TextProps<T> & Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof TextProps<T>>`.

What's even more confusing is that the `createElement` syntax works, and appears to pass type-checking.

```
return createElement(Text, { group: "display", size, tag, children })
```